# Wordpress - How to add a post without let it be shown in the RSS feed

Tags: wordpress

Sometimes I want to add posts to my blog and I dont want them to be shown in the RSS feed, so that suscribers will not get notified about them.
Is that possible?

Thank you vey much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find many answers by yourself:

http://web-kreation.com/all/4-ways-to-exclude-wordpress-category-from-rss-feeds/

http://www.clickonf5.org/wordpress/hide-post-from-rss-feed/10335